# What are some similarities and differences between the 2001 recession and the 2007 recession in terms of causes and the effects on the economy?

Tags: macroeconomics

I know the two were caused by the burst bubbles and worsened by rising interest rates. I also know that the the 2001 recession had a long jobless recovery but did not experience as many bank failures as the Great Recession. I'm assuming the stock market fell for both?

Comment: see https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/SPASTT01USM661N

Comment: This is probably too broad as there would be too many similarities and differences. You should add more context as to what specifically you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Noted.